# Rewrite javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

I´m rewriting some JavaScript and I´m stuck at this for loop (especially the `++idx >= length` part):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < b.data.byteLength && !(pos >= offset && (data.setUint8(idx, actualView.getUint8(i)), ++idx >= length)); i++) {
    pos++;
  }
```

How do I rewrite this for loop in a way that it doesn't contain any extra inline code (like `pos >= offset`, `data.setUint8(idx, actualView.getUint8(i)` and `++idx >= length` etc)?

Comment: You've haven't provided any context for that loop so it's difficult to help in this case. What is the loop iterating over, what is the expected result, and what are those other variables? It's unlikely you can eliminate those lines without breaking the code. What debugging have you done to work out what the code is doing? By understanding it yourself you can break it down and see what possible efficiencies can be made - if any.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to pull the value up into it's own function.

Without more context or knowledge of your variables this is the best I could come up with. Your question should be reworked to provide additional details if this does not help you.

```js
function getMaxIterationValue(b, pos, [...]){
  if(!b.data.byteLength);
    return 0;
  }

  // Not enough context in the question to help refactor this...
  // !(pos >= offset && (data.setUint8(idx, actualView.getUint8(i)), ++idx >= length)
  
}

for (var i = 0; i < getMaxIterationValue(b, pos, [...]); i++) {
    pos++;
  }
```